# Why doesn't random work?

Tags: java, testing, random

I have to write a method, which is able to find random Vacation in the database. But when I use this part in the test

```
Random id = new Random();
vacationId = id.nextInt(2500);
```

I get `NullPoiterExeption`.
But when i just print

```
vacationId = 2500;
```

or some other number, everything is okay.

This is the whole method

```
public Vacation findRandomVacation() {
    Integer vacationId = null;
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("from Vacation v where v.id = :id")
                .setParameter("id", vacationId);
    if  ( query.getResultList().isEmpty()) {
        Random id = new Random();
        vacationId = id.nextInt(2500);
        query = entityManager.createQuery("from Vacation v where v.id = :id")
               .setParameter("id", vacationId);
    }
    return (Vacation) query.getResultList().get(0);
}
```

And this is the main body of the test:

```
@Test
public void testVacationApprovalResultDao () {
    Vacation testVacation = findRandomVacation();
    VacationApproval testVacationApproval = findVacationApprovalDAO(testVacation);
    List<VacationApprovalResult> testVacationApprovalResult = getVacationApprovalResultByManager(testVacationApproval);
    Set<VacationApprovalResult> setVacationApprovalResult = testVacationApproval.getVacationApprovalResults();   //mistake is here
    List<VacationApprovalResult> testVacationApprovalResult2 = new ArrayList<VacationApprovalResult> ();
    testVacationApprovalResult2.addAll(setVacationApprovalResult);

    assertEquals(testVacationApprovalResult, testVacationApprovalResult2);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect *this* is where you get the `NullPointerException`:

```
Integer vacationId = null;
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("from Vacation v where v.id = :id")
            .setParameter("id", vacationId);
```

This is *before* you've set it from `Random` - you're setting the parameter to a null value.

To be honest though, this isn't a good way of finding a random record from the database unless you *know* that there are vacations with every ID from 0 to 2499.

Basically you want the random choice to be performed *at the database* as that's where the data is. An alternative would be to fetch *all* the vacation IDs, pick a random element of that set, and then load the data for it - but that's not pleasant either.

Comment: i know that there are vacations with every id. and when i put this vacationId = 2500; i change only the random part, not the first string

Comment: @JaneMakedonskaya: What string? There aren't any strings. `Random` itself is fine - so either there's more context that you haven't told us, or something very odd is going on. I really wouldn't expect it to get that far when you haven't provided a value of the `id` parameter. I suspect your diagnostics aren't quite right. It doesn't help that you haven't shown us where the exception is actually happening - please edit the stack trace into your question.

Comment: i mean line. i'm not native english speaker, sorry. the place, where exeption is happening is shown in the comment

Comment: @JaneMakedonskaya: Well that's several lines later - after calls to `findVacationApprovalDAO` and `getVacationApprovalResultByManager`... we have no idea what they do. You'll need to diagnose this further yourself. Perhaps the vacations you tried manually had some value that the random ones didn't.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet yes? you're right about the value. thanks, i'll continue diagnosing.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 Integer vacationId = null;
```

to

```
Integer vacationId = 0;
```

Comment: the same mistake in the same line:(

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do this ?

```
Integer vacationId = null;
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("from Vacation v where v.id = :id")
            .setParameter("id", vacationId);
```

Is it possible for vacationId to hold a null value ? if not then try with the random at once.